# list of pattern to be removed from the file

Tags: command-line, text-processing

To illustrate it further we have two file contents:

file1

```
hello
1_hello 
2_hello
world
1_world
2_world
hello1
1_hello1
2_hello1
world1
1_world1
2_world1
```

file2

```
This
hello
1_hello
2_hello
is world
1_world
2_world
my
hello1
1_hello1
2_hello1
word
world1
1_world1
2_world1
file
```

---

what I want is to iterate the first column of file1 and remove the entries which are matching in the file2 and produce the output like:

```
This
is
my 
word
file
```

How can I proceed?

Answer (score 5):

You want to use awk to read  file1 and remember all its words. Then read  file2 and output any words that were not seen from  file1:

```
gawk -v RS='[[:space:]]+' 'NR==FNR {words[$1]=1; next} !($1 in words)' file1 file2
```

That uses any sequence of whitespace as the record separator, so every word is treated as a separate "line". This now GNU awk specific, but that's the default awk on Ubuntu

Comment: It's just plain awesome, thank you for sharing this knowledge!

Comment: @dessert: If you want an even more elegant answer, see mine. ;-P

Answer (score 3):

You can use `grep -f FILE` to obtain patterns from a file `FILE`. In your case I recommend some additional flags (see explanation below) for the following final `grep` invocation:

```
grep -v -x -F -f file1 -- file2
```

- `-f FILE` – Obtain patterns from `FILE`, one per line.
- `-F` – Interpret the pattern as a list of fixed strings, separated by newlines, any of which is to be matched.
- `-x` – Select only those matches that exactly match the whole line. (You may want to remove this option if you want to allow partially matching lines.)
- `-v` – Invert the sense of matching, to select non-matching lines.

<sup>Source: the [GNU grep documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/html_node/Invoking.html#Invoking) or alternatively its [manual page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/grep.1.html)</sup>

All options used above are specified by POSIX and don't require GNU extensions.

Comment: Elegant indeed! +1 ;)

Answer (score 1):

This command line should do the trick:

```
while read -r word; do sed -e "s/\<$word\>//g" -e '/^\s*$/d' file2 -i; done < file1
```

After the execution of the above command, the output file - `file2` - should look as this:

```
This
is
my
word
file
```

---

More readable version of the above command line:

```
while read -r word; do \
    sed -e "s/\<$word\>//g" -e '/^\s*$/d' file2 -i; \
done < file1
```

The `while` loop reads the file line by line - `< file1`. The value of each line is used as a value of the temporary created variable, called `$word` - `-r word`. This variable is used as an argument within the command `sed` and it is substituted [`s`] by a blank value in `file2`, the first expression: `"s/\<$word\>//g"` = `s/<source_value>/<replacement_value>/g`. The `g` flag means - apply the replacement to all matches. Then if there is a blank line within the file it is removed - the second expression: `'/^\s*$/d'`.

We need to use the syntax `\<...\>`to find only the exact matches. We need double quote marks - `"..."` - for the first expression because `$word` is a name of variable and we want to expanded it as its value within the `sed` command.

The option `-i` means that the changes will be made in their places within the target file - `file2`. If this option is removed the result will be thrown to stdout but it will be not meaningful. The option `-i.bak` is not applicable to this scenario, because the target file  will be overwritten many times, so you should create a backup copy in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use grep with `-v` (invert) flag.

With using extended regex (`-E`), you can make a `|`-separated list of patterns, that you wish to exclude , e.g. `pattern1|pattern2|pattern3`:

```
grep -v -E "^[0-9]|world|hello" file
```

Answer (score 0):

Although the removing criteria is not very clear, I assume that the parts to remove are (`www\n1_www\n2_www`) for all word `www` (correct me if I am wrong)

Using (gnu)sed:

```
sed -zr 's/(\w+)\n1_\1\n2_\1\n//g' ex
```